# remove elements from listview in android

Tags: android, listview

i have 2 arrays productname and price. my each row in listview contains productname,price and an image button remove. when i click remove button,the selected productname and price **should be removed from my array** as well as from my listview. Please guide me doing this,is very important for me. If there is another way of doing this plz let me know.i m student only!

this is my CartActivity

```
public class CartActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {


CartAdapter contactAdapter;
ListView listView;
public String productname[]=new String[10];
public String price[]=new String[10];

int i=0,m;
CartActivity(String scanContent){
    this.content = scanContent;
}
public CartActivity() {}
String product,Price;
String pri,prod;
Intent intent;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);       
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.cart_list_view);

    contactAdapter = new CartAdapter(this,R.layout.activity_cart_list_view);
    listView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);

    intent = getIntent();
    productname = intent.getStringArrayExtra("productname");
    price = intent.getStringArrayExtra("price");

    for(int j=0;j<price.length;j++) {
        product = productname[j];
        Price = price[j];
        if (Price != null || product != null) {
            Cart contacts = new Cart(product, Price);
            contactAdapter.add(contacts);
        }
    }
}
```

this is my CartAdapter

```
public class CartAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
List list = new ArrayList();
int ind,x=0;
public  CartAdapter(CartActivity context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
}
public void add(Cart object) {
    super.add(object);
    list.add(object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row;
    row = convertView;

    ContactHolder contactHolder;
    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_cart_list_view,parent,false);
        contactHolder = new ContactHolder();
        contactHolder.tx_name =(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
        contactHolder.tx_price =(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.price);

        contactHolder.cancelButton = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);


        row.setTag(contactHolder);
    }

    else
    {
        contactHolder = (ContactHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    cancelButton.setTag(position);
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Integer index = (Integer) view.getTag();
                list.remove(index.intValue());
            notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });


    Cart contacts = (Cart) this.getItem(position);
    contactHolder.tx_name.setText(contacts.getItemname());
    contactHolder.tx_price.setText(contacts.getPrice());
    return row;
}

static class ContactHolder
{
    TextView tx_name,tx_price;
    ImageButton cancelButton;
}
}
```

this is my Cart

```
public class Cart {
private  String itemname,price;
public Cart(String itemname,String price) {
    this.setItemname(itemname);
    this.setPrice(price);
}
public void setItemname(String itemname) {
    this.itemname = itemname;
}
public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}
public String getItemname() {
    return itemname;
}
public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}
}
```

[my each row in a listview contains this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HALif.png)

Answer (score 2):

Just do this,

in your adapter class,

```
cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            list.remove(position);  //position is getView position
            // above line will remove from arraylist
            notifyDataSetChanged(); //this line reflects change in listview

        }
    });
```

To remove from Activity class,
better create an ArrayList first.

```
ArrayList<Cart> cardList = new ArrayList<Cart>();
```

add into arrayList,

```
if (Price != null || product != null) {
        Cart contacts = new Cart(product, Price);
        cardList.add(contacts);
        contactAdapter.add(contacts); // this line should be removed if you work with arrayList
    }
```

now create a method to remove from ActivityCard arrayList,

```
//call this method from cancelimage click in adapter class
public void removeFromList(int position){
    cardList.remove(position);  //this will remove from activity arraylist
}
```

At the end calculate your bill from existing cartList data.

*** You can also create adapter class object with cardList just changing your constructor. If you do this then just call removeFromList on cancelimage click and put,

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

after

> cardList.remove(position);

it will refresh your listview also.

Comment: Sir actually ther was mistake in previous code. please check it now. Yes item is removing from listview,But i want that element to be removed from my array which i am receiving via intent. Because i want that array to generate bill

Comment: can you please review the question again, I guess its changed again!

Comment: Sorry for unclarity sir. For example my both arrays has 5 items. so 5 items will be displayed in listview. If we click remove button at index 3 then it is removing from my listview / arraylist. But i want that index3 element to be removed from my productname nd price arrays.Please help!

Comment: Sir actually i m having some confusion as i am new in this field. Can you please make changes in my uploaded code and send it again?Please

Comment: Sure, I will do that

Comment: Yes Please! Sir i applied above code as per my interpretation but whenever i m try to access arraylist from removeFromList method it is giving me arrayindexoutofboundexception index:0 size0

Comment: items showing is the list?, is cardList.add(contacts); inside if (Price != null || product != null) {} block?

Comment: Yes sir, items are showing in the list and cardlist.add(contacts); is inside that if block

Comment: how many items are in list and when this error happens? to delete first item?

Comment: sir that exception is independent of the no. of items in the list... Arraylist is not empty but it is just not accessible within removeFromList method

Comment: are you sure items adding in cardList? see with log please

Comment: I m sure sir.. i have seen the log... This is the same problem i was facing with array nd now with arraylist

Comment: put contactAdapter = new CartAdapter(this,R.layout.activity_cart_list_view);
    listView.setAdapter(contactAdapter); after for loop